# View requires API Level 17 <TextClock>

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have set the minSdkVersion level to 8, which will allow everyone from Froyo to install and use the app, but when I try adding the TextClock view to the activity xml file, it says that the view requires API level 17.
If i set the minSdkVersion to 17, then no one using an android OS that's below level 17 will be able to install and use my app, right?
How do I get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: text clock back support did work for me :) here is the link github.com/vojtech/android-textclock-backport/branches

Answer (score 3):

> if i set the min sdk version to 17 then no one using an android OS
>   that below level 17 will be able to install and use my app right?

Correct. This is explained in the official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

> how do I get around this?

There are libraries around that provide a backward compatibility for that visual component, you could have a look at [android-textclock-backport](https://github.com/vojtech/android-textclock-backport) for example (although I didn't test it).

Comment: so if you use componets that are not supported by api levels below your target api level then you need to provide a backward compatibility class implementation for that component, right? But, even if you use a componet that is exclusive to say jelly bean then the application should run without any problems like displaying the component on the screen even if the user is using a phone with KitKat in it,  -- no backward compatibility implementation required, right? thanks.

Comment: Again correct, almost looks like you actually don't need me to explain ;) Min SDK means a phone running a *lower* version of Android cannot install use the app, but higher version is fine. The component is available *as from* API 17, so a phone running KitKat (API 19) can use it as well.

Comment: Just one last question. I understand what you are saying but If I set the _target_ sdk to API 17 and use a component that is unique to API 17 then will users still be able to install the app and use the component on a phone that is running KitKat(API 19)? thanks.

Comment: I think it is better if you just set the targetSdk to the latest one available to avoid issues (setting targetSdk to 19 does not prevent you from using components that are available *as from* sdk 17, what was available in sdk 17 still is there in sdk 19), although devices running KitKat should be able to run it with targetSdk 17.

Comment: it did work for me, i just had to remove the support library in that project as i am already using it in mine :)